# C++ Two Threads, One Writing Global Values, One Reading Global Values, Do I need some lock?

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, locking

Sorry if this was asked before, I haven't found any similar questions where one thread writes and one reads.
All the ones I found have both reading.

I read so much that you need some kind of lock if you have one thread writing information while another thread reading?

But what exactly must I to do?, at the moment I plan to do it like this below.

```
int test = 0;
bool testBool = false;

void writeThread() {
  while(1) {
    test += 1;
    testBool != testBool;
    Sleep(10); //10 milliseconds wait.
  }
}

void readThread() {
  while(1) {
    int testRem = test % 100;
    if((testRem => 0 && testRem < 20) && testBool) {
      printf("is this fine? test=%d", test);
    }
    Sleep(10); //10 milliseconds wait.
  }
}

CreateThread(NULL,0,(LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)&writeThread,0,NULL,NULL); 
CreateThread(NULL,0,(LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)&readThread,0,NULL,NULL);
```

I am not worried if it misses the remainder being 0 which could happen since before it reads the write already incremented past it, but I don't worry about that issue sorry for the bad example, I just want to make sure it doesn't crash and doesn't give me a undefined behavior value for the global variable.

I'll be using `bool`'s in both threads to indicate whether or not it to run the code inside both threads (read/write threads).

The bool's which are updated using `GetAsyncKeyState` in a third thread for detecting keypresses.

Reason why I must do this is because while i'm running a very slow delayed keypresses in readThread, I want to be able to get freshly updated `int` values at the same time while the readThread is paused for the delayed keypresses which I could do in one thread I guess by putting the update `int` values code in a function I guess, but this update `int` values must be ran every 10 milliseconds either way without any pauses. (I'll probably take this path if I can't do two threads of read/write without problems).

**As long as it doesn't crash or give me undefined behavior for `int`'s or `bool`'s after long time running it. Then it's fine**

Comment: If you are blessed with a modern enough compiler, replace `int test` with `atomic<int> test`, and your code will be fine.

Comment: You'll need to have some synchronization mechanism like a mutex or semaphore ..

Comment: `error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int`  with `atomic<int> test` Must not be supported by Visual C++ 2010 Express.

Comment: Depending on your platform, 32-bit read/writes might be atomic anyway. What problem are you trying to solve though? If you want to guarantee that the read thread won't miss an instance of `test %100 == 0` being true, that's a harder problem to solve than the atomicity of the actual read/write.

Comment: You should be using some type of signalling mechanism rather than polling. Using an event object with something like [WaitForSingleObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687032(v=vs.85).aspx) or [WaitForMultipleObjects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687025(v=vs.85).aspx) should do the trick.

Comment: @SSpoke try `std::atomic<int> test = ATOMIC_VAR_INIT(0);` and be sure to include `<atomic>`

Comment: @WhozCraig I don't seem to have the atomic header in Visual C++ 2010 Express, `fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'atomic': No such file or directory`

Comment: just upgrade - the latest express is free too.

Comment: I tried the newest one doesn't run on my computer without lagging issues I run an old Windows XP OS, Dual Core with 2 GB Ram. Unless I could upgrade my old express with latest express headers/compiling somehow.

Comment: Don't even think about that. Anyhow for your particular problem you can just mark the variable volatile as long as you're using just visual studio under x86

Comment: Or, best case use `InterlockedIncrement` which will prevent the need to upgrade and also leverages the CPU's own ability to perform this operation without the overhead of mutexes.